# Adapter no se ejecuta bien

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, adapter

tengo un Adapter que no consigo que se ejecute correctamente en cierto momento.

De normal la aplicación se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando busco un nombre o un ID de un digimon distinto, el RecyclerView de abajo, el de "Campos", se ve tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y eso pasa únicamente cuando hago una petición nueva a la API.

Esto en la MainActivity:

```
binding.buttonSearch.setOnClickListener {
            val busqueda = binding.editTextTextDigiNameOrId.text.toString()
            digiViewModel.buscarDigimon(busqueda)
        }
```

Y esto en el ViewModel:

```
fun buscarDigimon(param: String) {
        repository.setParam(param)
        cargarDatos()
    }
```

Y esto donde se define la interface donde consumir la API

```
interface DigiApiService{
    @GET("/api/v1/digimon/{param}")
    suspend fun getDigimon(@Path(value = "param") param: String) : Digi
}
```

Una vez ha hecho el recorrido, y vuelve a cargar los valores, el Adapter del RecyclerView no vuelve a mostrar las imágenes, y no entiendo el por qué.

Gracias de antebrazo.

Imagen de un digimon con "campos" para demostrar que no se dibujan:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo primero es revisar si la petición a la API obtiene información. agrega también cargarDatos().

Comment: Hacerlo lo hace porque sino no obtendría nada de primera vez, y la segunda crea los huecos pero no pinta la imagen. Es raro. A parte, lo he debugeado y si, aparecen todos los campos que requiero, pero no los pinta.

Comment: gracias ya lo tengo

Comment: Vale, a ver si puedes ayudarme a comprenderlo, porque me parece raro

Answer (score 0):

La razón por la cual no obtienes "campos" con otros "digimones" (no sé cómo se llamen haha), es que **para algunos animales, la API simplemente no retorna valores en `fields`**, por ejemplo, si buscas **`Petitmon`**, la API retorna la respuesta con un array `fields` vacío (`fields=[]`):

> Digi(id=200, name=Petitmon, xAntibody=false,
> images=[DigiImagen(href=https://digimon-api.com/images/digimon/w/Petitmon.png,
> transparent=false)], levels=[DigiLevel(id=5, level=Baby I)],
> types=[DigiType(id=6, type=Slime)], attributes=[DigiAttribute(id=2,
> attribute=Free)], **fields=[]**, releaseDate=0,.........

En cambio al buscar un **`Agumon`** si obtienes un array `fields` con valores.

> Digi(id=289, name=Agumon, xAntibody=false,
> images=[DigiImagen(href=https://digimon-api.com/images/digimon/w/Agumon.png, transparent=false)], levels=[DigiLevel(id=7, level=Child)],
> types=[DigiType(id=45, type=Reptile)], attributes=[DigiAttribute(id=3,
> attribute=Vaccine)], **fields=[DigiFields(id=4, field=Unknown),
> DigiFields(id=1, field=Nature Spirits), DigiFields(id=2, field=Virus
> Busters), DigiFields(id=5, field=Metal Empire), DigiFields(id=8,
> field=Nightmare Soldiers), DigiFields(id=9, field=Dragon's Roar)]**,
> releaseDate=0,.....................

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero si buscas otro pokemon y vuelves a buscar a agumon NO se dibujan. Voy a editar la pregunta para que lo veas. Fuera a parte, he puesto un ejemplo, Gabumon, que si que tiene campos.

Comment: Si busco petitmon y luego agumon si me muestra los campos :0,

Comment: Pues ahí tienes la prueba de que a mi no XD